# Finding a function $f(x,y)$ that has a limit at $(0,0)$ using standard tricks $(y= mx, y +ax^2)$ but fails along $(0, \sin x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm looking for a function $f(x,y)$ that has a limit at $(0,0)$ using standard tricks $(y= mx, y +ax^2)$ but fails along $(0, \sin x)$. I apologize for not knowing enough LaTex. This is not a homework problem for me to do. Rather, I am the instructor and I want to use it on a take home assignment. Are there conditions which guarantee such behavior. I don't teach Calculus III very often and I think this would be instructive both for me and my students.

Comment: Like $f(x,y)=1- \dfrac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)}?$

Comment: @Narasimham It seems the limit of $f(x,y)$ exists and is equal $0.$

Comment: What about $f(0,y)= 1$ for $y\neq 0$ and $f(x,y)=1$ for $x\neq 0$ ?

Comment: I think you can simply take $f(x,y)=1$ iff $y=\sin x$ and $f(x,y)=0$. , $otherwise$ .